# nicely formatted python code in html files

Tags: html, css

What are the options to display python code in HTML pages?

I do not want to execute python code in the page, but only produce HTML/CSS pages displaying nicely formatted (with e.g., syntax highlighting) python code snippets as done, for instance, by stackoverflow.

Basically I would like a tool that takes a python file as input and generate an HTML/CSS code.

Comment: You can use either `<pre>` or `<code>` tags.

Comment: For syntax highlighting, what you're looking for is called a code prettifier. There's a lot of options for that available online, look into it and see if one fits your needs (Stack Overflow doesn't allow recommendation questions unfortunately).

Comment: @EternalHour : thanks for your answer.  I did not know of theses tags

Comment: @john-montgomery : thank you.  I did not know it was called like that (code prettifier).  I have found a couple of tools that seem nice.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Update:**
I just discovered [highlightjs.org](https://highlightjs.org/), which supports over 189 languages and 91 styles, and way easier to use. There is a code sample below:

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.0.3/styles/default.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.0.3/highlight.min.js"></script>
  <script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
</head>
<body>
  <pre><code class="python">def fib(n):
  a, b = 0, 1
    while a < n:
      print(a, end=' ')
      a, b = b, a+b
      print()
  fib(1000)</code></pre>
</body>
```

---

**Origina Post:**

Try [codemirror.net](https://codemirror.net/). More info [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198271/is-there-a-good-in-browser-code-editor) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53510125/how-can-i-visually-display-a-block-of-python-code-utilizing-html-css-and-javascr) from Stack Overflow

Or like @EternalHour said, you can use `<pre>Your code here</pre>` `<code>Your code here</code>`

Answer (score 1):

you can use [pygments](https://pygments.org/) for styling python codes in your html pages.